# How to disable input fields but not the clicked one and then enable all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

I have some buttons in my project and I want to disable all if one button is clicked but not the clicked one. When I click again the button, I want to enable all of them.
This is what I tried and didn't work :

```js
$('#TOSTORAGE').click(function(){
  $('#TOULD').prop('disabled', true\false);
  $('#TOTRAIN').prop('disabled', true\false);
  $('#TOARRIVAL').prop('disabled', true\false);
  $('#TOHANDLER').prop('disabled', true\false);
});
$('#TOULD').click(function(){
  $('#TOSTORAGE').prop('disabled', true\false);
  $('#TOTRAIN').prop('disabled', true\false);
  $('#TOARRIVAL').prop('disabled', true\false);
  $('#TOHANDLER').prop('disabled', true\false);
});
$('#TOTRAIN').click(function(){
  $('#TOSTORAGE').prop('disabled', true\false);
  $('#TOULD').prop('disabled', true\false);
  $('#TOARRIVAL').prop('disabled', true\false);
  $('#TOHANDLER').prop('disabled', true\false);
});
$('#TOARRIVAL').click(function(){
  $('#TOSTORAGE').prop('disabled', true\false);
  $('#TOULD').prop('disabled', true\false);
  $('#TOTRAIN').prop('disabled', true\false);
  $('#TOHANDLER').prop('disabled', true\false);
});
$('#TOHANDLER').click(function(){
  $('#TOSTORAGE').prop('disabled', true\false);
  $('#TOULD').prop('disabled', true\false);
  $('#TOTRAIN').prop('disabled', true\false);
  $('#TOARRIVAL').prop('disabled', true\false);
});
```

```css
.btn-hl2{
color:#ffffff;
height:90px;
width: 340px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 6px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #536e7f;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    font-size: 34px;
    font-family: inherit;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    font:#FFF;    
}

.btn-hl3{
color:#ffffff;
height:90px;
width: 695px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 6px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #536e7f;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    font-size: 34px;
    font-family: inherit;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    font:#FFF;    
}

.btn-hl2:hover {
        background-color: #e4b527;
    }
.btn-hl3:hover {
        background-color: #e4b527;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="TOSTORAGE" type="submit" class="btn-hl2" name="TOSTORAGE">
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span> TO STORAGE
</button>  
<button id="TOULD" type="submit" class="btn-hl2" name="TOULD">
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span> TO ULD
</button>
<button id="TOTRAIN" type="submit" class="btn-hl2" name="TOTRAIN">
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span> TO TRAIN
</button>
<button id="TOARRIVAL" type="submit" class="btn-hl2" name="TOARRIVAL">
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span> TO ARRIVAL
</button>
<button id="TOHANDLER" type="submit" class="btn-hl3" name="TOHANDLER">
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span> TO HANDLER
</button>
```

Comment: What's `true\false`?

Comment: Why not just use radio buttons?

Comment: First I need to POST something to server, then I will scan a barecode, and then I close the Session.

Answer (score 1):

You can set **common class name** and achieve by the following way:

```js
$('.btn-common').click(function(){
 $('.btn-common').prop('disabled', true);
 $(this).prop('disabled', false);
});
```

```css
.btn-hl2{
    color:#ffffff;
    height:90px;
    width: 340px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 6px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #536e7f;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    font-size: 34px;
    font-family: inherit;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    font:#FFF;    
}

.btn-hl3{
    color:#ffffff;
    height:90px;
    width: 695px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 6px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #536e7f;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    font-size: 34px;
    font-family: inherit;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    font:#FFF;    
}
.btn-common:disabled {
    background: #dddddd;
}
.btn-hl2:hover {
    background-color: #e4b527;
}
.btn-hl3:hover {
    background-color: #e4b527;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="TOSTORAGE" type="submit" class="btn-hl2 btn-common" name="TOSTORAGE">
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span> TO STORAGE
</button>  
<button id="TOULD" type="submit" class="btn-hl2 btn-common" name="TOULD">
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span> TO ULD
</button>
<button id="TOTRAIN" type="submit" class="btn-hl2 btn-common" name="TOTRAIN">
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span> TO TRAIN
</button>
<button id="TOARRIVAL" type="submit" class="btn-hl2 btn-common" name="TOARRIVAL">
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span> TO ARRIVAL
</button>
<button id="TOHANDLER" type="submit" class="btn-hl3 btn-common" name="TOHANDLER">
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span> TO HANDLER
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('button').not(this).prop('disabled', function(i, state) {
    return !state;
  });
});
```

```css
button:disabled{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>button 1</button>
<button>button 2</button>
<button>button 3</button>
<button>button 4</button>
```

*( edit1 with better selector **.not( )** instead of **.siblings( )** )*

*( edit2 simplier solution)*

Comment: For Handle(Mobile) didn't work, only for desktop. Why ?

Comment: I tested it on mobile (iOS 10, Safari, jQuery 2.2.1 - onload) and it works. Can you provide your setup?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Note 5, Android 6.0.1, Chrome 51.0.2704.81

Comment: jQuery version? try my new edit, and if it not works link me your buildup. Here's the edit's fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/akosb/acwves3e/

Comment: I used 2.1.1 and 3.0.0 and are no difference !

Comment: It's worked now ! Thank you very much ! But now is hard to make a button to send a HTTP POST to Controller (MVC). When the button is pressed i want to make multiple scanning of a Barecode PDF 417 and want to send 4 key to controller. So when i scan something when the button pressed and active to SAVE information on the barecode. (I have the script for scanning/parsing barecode)

Comment: If you'd like, I can contact you or help in an other stackoverflow thread.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349911/http-post-for-each-laser-scanning-barcode-2d-jquery-mvc -> this is the thread

Answer (score 0):

```
Check this demo using jquery
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="TOSTORAGE" type="submit" class="btn-hl2" name="TOSTORAGE">
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span> TO STORAGE
</button>  
<button id="TOULD" type="submit" class="btn-hl2" name="TOULD">
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span> TO ULD
</button>
<button id="TOTRAIN" type="submit" class="btn-hl2" name="TOTRAIN">
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span> TO TRAIN
</button>
<button id="TOARRIVAL" type="submit" class="btn-hl2" name="TOARRIVAL">
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span> TO ARRIVAL
</button>
<button id="TOHANDLER" type="submit" class="btn-hl3" name="TOHANDLER">
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span> TO HANDLER
</button>
```

**JS**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.enableDisable = function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            this.disabled = !this.disabled;
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$('button').click(function(e) {
  $('button').not(this).enableDisable();
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvpe49b9/5/)

Comment: Fiddles die someday, so you should at least provide some content to make your answer relevant in some years.

Comment: @Adder i understood your point, so i have also pasted piece of code from my fiddle..